# React Native Android Apk

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle, apk

i can't get export from even new project. ./gradlew clean work but ./gradlew assembleRelease doesn't work.

`java --version :openjdk 21 2023-09-19 OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu21.28+85-CA (build 21+35) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu21.28+85-CA (build 21+35, mixed mode, sharing)`

build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    targetSdkVersion = 33

    // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
    ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
}
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
    classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
}}
```

gradle version:distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.1-all.zip

and the error is :

> Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidJdkImage'.
> Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/mehdinasiripoor/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-33/core-for-system-modules.jar.
> > Error while executing process /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/mehdinasiripoor/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c40273315238db45e8af12bd10f1acc3/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/mehdinasiripoor/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c40273315238db45e8af12bd10f1acc3/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?